# Exception when building Expression to call StringBuilder.Append(Object) with DateTime

Tags: c#, expression

I've built a ToStringBuilder (found [here](https://github.com/chillitom/ToStringBuilder)) which reflects on types and dynamically builds `Expression`s to compile fast `ToString` methods.

It works well but I've just discovered it errors on `DateTimes`.  It chokes when trying to build an call to `StringBuilder.Append(Object)` passing a `DateTime`.  Do I need to create an expression to box value types? How is this best done?

I've created the following test case to demonstrate the failure.

```
    // passes
    [Test]
    public void AppendDateTime()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(new DateTime());
    }


    // throws 
    [Test]
    public void ExpressionAppendDateTime()
    {
        ParameterExpression sbArgExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StringBuilder), "sb");
        ParameterExpression dateTimeArgExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime), "dateTime");

        var appendMethod = typeof(StringBuilder).GetMethod("Append", new[] {typeof(DateTime)});
        var call = Expression.Call(sbArgExpression, appendMethod, dateTimeArgExpression);

        // throws on this line
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<StringBuilder, DateTime>>(call, sbArgExpression, dateTimeArgExpression).Compile();  

        var datetime = new DateTime();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        lambda.Invoke(sb, datetime);
    }
```

The exception is..

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Object' of method 'System.Text.StringBuilder Append(System.Object)'
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arg, ParameterInfo pi)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
       at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)
       at Tests.TestToStringBuilder.ExpressionAppendDateTime() in 
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 4):

Solved it, had to use `Expression.TypeAs` to type non-primitive value types as `Object`

```
    [Test]
    public void ExpressionAppendDateTime()
    {
        ParameterExpression sbArgExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StringBuilder), "sb");
        ParameterExpression dateTimeArgExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DateTime), "dateTime");

        var appendMethod = typeof(StringBuilder).GetMethod("Append", new[] {typeof(DateTime)});

        Type t = typeof(DateTime);
        Expression arg;
        if (t.IsValueType && !t.IsPrimitive)
        {
            arg = Expression.TypeAs(dateTimeArgExpression, typeof(object));
        }
        else
        {
            arg = dateTimeArgExpression;
        }

        var call = Expression.Call(sbArgExpression, appendMethod, arg);

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<StringBuilder, DateTime>>(call, sbArgExpression, dateTimeArgExpression).Compile();

        var datetime = new DateTime();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        lambda.Invoke(sb, datetime);
    }
```